# Connection code to the database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database

My database name is [chitomiho] and my table name is [trytable].
I want code for connecting to database and insert values into try table in asp.net

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great tutorial on connecting to a database in ASP.Net. We're not here to write code for you, only to help you when you're stuck.

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_dbconnection.asp

Answer (score 0):

Dear Inspiron this is a forum question and not meant to be asked here. If you would have just googled it!!!!

You may find this helpful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178371.aspx